# How to pass string from one UIViewController to another using 'performSegue' and UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to do simple barcode scanner in swift but I have a problem with passing String with scanned code to another UIViewController. On first view there is TextField and Button which change view to the second one which open phone camera.
I want it to pass scanned code to text field in first view and switch back to first view but I get an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver has no segue with
> identifier 'BarcodeSegue'

[image: 1]

First view controller:

```
import UIKit

class BarcodeViewController: UIViewController {
    var scannedCode: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var scannedCodeTextField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let code = scannedCode {
            scannedCodeTextField.text = code
        }
    }
}
```

Second view controller without code for scanning (BarcodeScannerViewController class):

```
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            if let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject,
               let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue {
                
                scannedCode = stringValue
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "BarcodeSegue", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? BarcodeViewController {
            destination.scannedCode = scannedCode
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/resource_management/dismissing_a_view_controller_with_an_unwind_segue)

Comment: It looks like the segue needs to be called from `BarcodeViewController` rather than from `BarcodeScannerViewController`. Am I reading your code right? You're calling the segue from the rightmost view controller in the screen shot, but the segue looks like it sends from the middle view controller to the one on the right?

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. Unwind segue fixed my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)